# Console Window not Opening in Dev C++? Even with getch() too?

Tags: c++

I am using Dev cpp 5.1 and it is not opening console window on running the program. One of the basic program which I tried is

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

  using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout<<"A";
  getch();
}
```

Comment: What *compiler* (probably [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and *version* are you using? DevCpp is only an IDE...

Comment: Did you try to run your program in some command window?

Comment: This could be caused by your antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what compiler you are using, you might want to try using _getch() or getchar() instead of getch().